# Will the isolation provided by Dart would be useful to execute navigator of push seperately

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a linear array of cards shown via list view builder where tapping on a card will lead to a new page. I used navigator.push to do achieve this but it seems like a stack will be generated for the push that actually rebuilds the entire widget(to be updated), on behalf of this the rendering of second screen has become slow FYI My first screen have numerous amount of cards scattered under a sticky header. would the isolation provided by dart is useful for this scenario if so how to achieve it?

note:
I mean running navigator push in one isolation and rebuilding of widget for push stack in another isolation

Comment: This sounds like your build method is doing actual work, which it shouldn't, (except building the widget tree of course).

Comment: During any navigation call(s), your current screen widget (and children widget in the widget tree) will get setState(...) call if they're stateful. And runtime exception is thrown if setState() is called on a widget that is currently being built, regardless of which isolate is running it.

Comment: If you're seeing performance issues it might be worth posting some code (hopefully the smallest subset which shows the issue). Also, have you tried running in release mode as that tends to be way faster than debug mode...